# How to make UI text longer?

Tags: unity, gui, text

I'm working on a menu that needs a wordy description, but I've noticed that it only shows 4 letters, then cuts off and this doesn't seem right.

I right click, select UI > text and again, it only displays 4 words, even though I can write a lot more there. Am I doing something wrong here?

I'm not sure how to get past this and I want to ask if anyone knows how to get past this? It seems like such a strange limit to put on the UI canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the fix to this is very simple and you can easily miss it. On the text options, you want to scroll down to  Vertical Overflow and change that from 'Truncate' to 'Overflow' this will no longer limit the amount of words you can display. You can do the same with Horizontal Overflow as well.

I hope this helps somebody :)

Comment: You can also use the text object's transform component, or its parent layout components, to adjust the size of its layout bounding box. By default, it will show text inside that box, so if you make the box too small it might not all fit. This gives you finer layout control than just letting everything overflow.